# Create function not saving data to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get the create function to have the user selected values entered into the database. When the create button is pushed, no error is thrown but, the data is not populated. I'm pretty sure my frequency fields are causing the issue but have been unable to come with a solution.

There are two different types of frequencies a user can select depending upon their "Notification Name" selection. One selection has 3 separate fields for a numerical value, time frame (week, month etc.), and a before/after selection. The other simply states instantaneous as a static text field. Regardless of which option is chosen the frequency data should be populated into one cell within the database which is then separated using piping where necessary. I'm still pretty new to C# MVC so any help is greatly appreciated.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,notificationType1,recipientTypeId,frequency")] NotificationType notificationType)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.NotificationType.Add(notificationType);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }

        ViewBag.recipientTypeId = new SelectList(db.RecipientType, "Id", "recipientRole", notificationType.recipientTypeId);
        return View(notificationType);
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.notificationType1, "Notification Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 helper-format" })
            <div class="col-md-10" id="type_selection">
                @Html.DropDownList("notificationType1", new List<SelectListItem> {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Make a Selection", Value="" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Incomplete Documents", Value= "Incomplete Documents" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "All Documents Complete", Value = "All Documents Complete" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Documents Requiring Action", Value = "Documents Requiring Action" }
                   }, new { @class = "helper-format", @id = "value_select", style = "font-family: 'Roboto', Sans Serif;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.notificationType1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="frequency_group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.frequency, "Frequency", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="frequency_group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.frequency, new { @class = "textbox-width", @placeholder = "42" })

                @Html.DropDownList("frequency", new List<SelectListItem>
       {
           new SelectListItem { Text = "Day(s)", Value= "| Day"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Week(s)", Value= "| Week"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Month(s)", Value= "| Month"}
       })

                @Html.DropDownList("frequency", new List<SelectListItem>
       {
           new SelectListItem { Text = "Before", Value= "| Before"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "After", Value= "| After"}
       })
            </div>
            <p class="col-sm-2" id="psdatetext">The Beginning</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="freq_instant">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.frequency, "Frequency", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="instant_text">  
            <p>Instantaneous</p></div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.recipientTypeId, "Notification For", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("recipientTypeId", new List<SelectListItem>
       {
           new SelectListItem { Text = "Me", Value= "Me"},
           new SelectListItem { Text = "Account Manager", Value="Account Manager" },
           new SelectListItem { Text = "Candidate", Value= "Candidate"},
           new SelectListItem { Text = "Recruiter", Value="Recruiter" },
           new SelectListItem { Text = "Manager", Value= "Manager"}
       })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                <div id="hovercreate">
                    <button type="submit" value="CREATE" class="btn btn-primary" id="createbtn">CREATE</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

JS for frequency options

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#frequency_group').hide()
    $('#freq_instant').hide()

    $('#value_select').change(function () {
        var selection = $('#value_select').val();
        $('#frequency_group').hide();
        switch (selection) {
            case 'Incomplete Documents':
                $('#frequency_group').show();
                break;
            case 'All Documents Complete':
                $('#frequency_group').show();
                break;
        }
    });

    $('#value_select').on('change', function () {
        if (this.value == 'Documents Requiring Action') {
            $("#freq_instant").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#freq_instant").hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Is this using Entity Framework Code First? If so, why don't you check the SQL that is being issued? Add a logger to ctx.Database.Log, maybe write to the trace output.

Comment: Watch your HTTP requests using your browser's network tools. Is the form POSTing to the right URL?

Comment: Put a break point, debug and find out if there is any error in the data you are sending.

Comment: Add following above your Class NotificationType [Bind(Include = "Id,notificationType1,recipientTypeId,frequency")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you placed a break-point on the method? And if so, is it triggering?

If not, try this...

From what I remember, all Controllers has a default parameter of ID which is set in the RouteConfig.cs file (App_Start/RouteConfig.cs).

There's a couple of ways to go from there.
1. Give the controller the ID parameter (e.g. (int ID))
2. Set the route value via the Route attribute

To do this you need to -
 A. Add the following at the top of your RouteConfig.cs / RegisterRoutes method.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");                   
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    //...
}
```

B. Add

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route(@"Create/")]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = ...
{
```

I would also suggest putting a break-point at the beginning of the method to see if its hitting it.

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routecollectionattributeroutingextensions.mapmvcattributeroutes%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Is the Id key manually assigned? If not (for example, if it's an IDENTITY field), you shouldn't be binding it - remove Id from [Bind(Include = "...")].